# Lost a file using git bash

Tags: bash, git, github

The last commands I ran with git bash resulted in the contents of my .css file being completely deleted.. the file is still there just empty. im new to git and have no clue what happened.
I have all of my commands here they are:

```
git branch modify  
git checkout modify  
git status  
git add .  
git commit -a -m "my message"  
git push origin modify  
git push origin master  
git push origin master  
git branch -D contact_nav
```

I don't know why I pushed to modify then master twice, I am assuming that's probably where something went wrong.

I have no backup commits, this was the first commit i made after all of my changes to the files.  Only the css is gone, my html and javascript, with all of their new changes are still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sequence of actions Git will perform with your commands:

```
git branch modify
#Create a branch 'modify'

git checkout modify
#Chekout to branch 'modify'

git status
#See the status of changed files since your last pull or clone

git add .
#add all the changed files in your current directory to the staging area. Now Git 
#starts tracking these files.

git commit -a -m "my message"
#Commit the tracking area changes and give it a revision (SHA1). Here -a is not needed because you have already run git add command.

git push origin modify
#Push to modify. This will push all the changes from the staging area to branch modify.

git push origin master
#Now you are trying to push your changes to the master branch. However, since the changes 
#are already pushed to the staging area, there is no new change to push to master.

git push origin master
#Same as the previous command

git branch -D contact_nav
#Now you are force deleting branch 'contact_nav'
```

What you need to do to get your css file changes back:

```
git branch
#This will tell which branch you are in. If it shows 'modify' as green then you are 
#in that branch. If not, then use command `git checkout modify`

git log
#Check if it shows your commit with a message "my message" as latest change.
#If you do not see such commit then you made your css change in some different branch. In this case, you need to make those css changes here in this branch. Once you edit the css file, again you need to execute commands 
#git add .
#git commit -m "my message"
#git push origin modify


#In case you see your .csv commit then you need to run below command
git reset --hard <SHA1 of your change with commit message "my message">
#This will bring your local to the change where you added content to .csv file. 
#And you have your changes back.
```

Answer (score 0):

The first command, git checkout modify, could have overwritten the .css file content, if said file was empty in that branch.
Your other files, if they were private and not versioned in that branch, would have been ignored by the checkout command: they would have stay as-is in the working tree, ready to be added and committed, which you did.

The problem is: if the css content was never at least added to the index, it content is lost, unless your editor/IDE has it in its own local history.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing commits in reflog?

```
$ git reflog | grep contact_nav
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: sorry, i'm not sure what this means.